# Adding Multiple Filters to an existing Filter in ElasticsearchPhp

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am a beginner and working on elasticsearch php for a simple search.
I have to set filters conditionally based on weather the filter is selected or not.
Hence I have made the filters for that specific task and placed them in different files. All i do is include these files when the isset returns true.
But the trouble is, if more than one filter is selected, then the last filter overwrites the filter part of array and does not provide the required multiple filtered answer. Is there anyway to make this work?
(Please pardon me if it is inefficient as I am a beginner and just trying to learn.)

My files are something like this

BalFilter.php

```
<?php

if ($val == 1) {
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter'] = ['range' => [
            'balance' => ['gte' => $bal]
        ]
    ];
}
if ($val == 2) {
    $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter'] = ['range' => [
            'balance' => ['lte' => $bal]
        ]
    ];
}
```

AgeFilter.php

```
<?php
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['term'] = ['age' => $age];
```

OnlyQuery.php

```
<?php 
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['query'] = [ 'query_string' => [
                                                  'default_field' => '_all',
                                                  'query' => $q,
                                                  'lenient' => true
                                                                ]
                                               ];
```

And in the main index

```
if (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    $age = $_GET['age'];
} else {
    $age = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['val'])) {
    $val = $_GET['val'];
} else {
    $val = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['bal'])) {
    $bal = $_GET['bal'];
} else {
    $bal = 0;
}

include "OnlyQuery.php";

if ($age != 0) {
    include "AgeFilter.php";
}
if (($val == 0 && $bal != 0) || ($val != 0 && $bal == 0)) {
    echo "Please choose the right combination for balance";
}
if ($val != 0 && $bal != 0) {
    include "BalFilter.php";
}
```

Comment: For multiple filters, you can use `AND` filter. Here is the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-and-filter.html

Comment: Can you show the content of `OnlyQuery.php`?

Comment: @Samir 'AND' does not support 'gte' and 'lte' filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to create a `bool/must` filters array that gets populated by each of your filter in the included file. This can be done either in `OnlyQuery.php` or just after including `OnlyQuery.php`, basically like this:

```
...
include "OnlyQuery.php";

$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter'] = array('bool' => [
    'must' => []
]);
...
```

Then `AgeFilter.php` can be changed to this:

```
$term = array('term' => ['age' => $age]);
array_push($params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'], $term);
```

And `BalFilter.php` to this

```
if ($val == 1) {
    $range = array('range' => [
        'balance' => ['gte' => $bal]
    ]);
    array_push($params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'], $range);
}
if ($val == 2) {
    $range = array('range' => [
        'balance' => ['lte' => $bal]
    ]);
    array_push($params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'], $range);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
But one thing i did not understand is why the array elements were getting replaced instead of getting added, since i am not referring to its actual position of the filter.